# Java return array

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm working on a simple application which returns the student mark based on the particular module. My main issue is with the `getModuleMark` method, because I need it to return the module mark given the module index.

For the `setModuleMark` method I have passed both the index module and marks parameters in. I'm just getting a little confused as to what I need to put in the return for module marks.

At the moment when I run the application I get the following output:

> Joe Bloggs
>
> Module 0: 50.0
>
> Module 1: 50.0
>
> Module 7: 50.0

See code below:

```
public class Student {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Student student = new Student("Joe", "Bloggs"); 
   
    // Add some marks to the student. 
    student.setModuleMark(0, 10);   
    student.setModuleMark(1, 80);  
    student.setModuleMark(7, 50);
  
   
    // Display the marks.
    System.out.println(student.getForename() + " " +     student.getSurname());
    System.out.println("Module 0: " + student.getModuleMark(0));
    System.out.println("Module 1: " + student.getModuleMark(1));
    System.out.println("Module 7: " + student.getModuleMark(7));
      } 
    
  

    private String forename;
    private String surname;
    private double marks;

    public Student(String forename, String surname) {
      super();
      this.forename = forename;
      this.surname = surname; 
    
      double [] ModuleMark = new double [7]; //Creates array of fixed size 7
    }
  
    /**
     * @return the forename
     */
     public String getForename() { 
        return this.forename;
     }
  
     /**
      * @return the surname
      */
     public String getSurname() {
       return this.surname;
     }
  
     /**
      * @param marks the marks to set
      * @param i 
      */     
     public double getModuleMark (int in) {
       return this.marks;        
     }
  
     public void setModuleMark(int in, double marks) {
     
    this.marks = marks;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot things which seem to be wrong.

First, the `ModuleMark` should be declared in the class and not within the constructor.

```
private double[] ModuleMark; // Declare here

public MyMain(String forename, String surname) {
    this.forename = forename;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.ModuleMark = new double[7]; // Creates array of fixed size 7
}
```

Next, your getModuleMarks and setModuleMarks method need to be like this

```
public double getModuleMark(int in) {
    return this.ModuleMark[in]; // return the value present at the given index
}

public void setModuleMark(int in, double marks) {
    this.ModuleMark[in] = marks; // set the marks at the given index in the array.
}
```

Also, since the `ModuleMark` is an array of **size 7**, you can't use the *index 7*. It would throw an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), because in an array, the maximum possible accessible index is always `array.length - 1`.

```
student.setModuleMark(6, 50); // The max possible index
...
System.out.println("Module 7: " + student.getModuleMark(6)); // The max possible index
```

**Note:** After these changes, `private double marks;` would no longer be in use. You can either discard it or have it if you're going to use it for some other purpose in the future.

Answer (score 1):

public class Student {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Student student = new Student("Joe", "Bloggs"); 

// Add some marks to the student. 
student.setModuleMark(0, 10);   
student.setModuleMark(1, 80);  
student.setModuleMark(7, 50);


// Display the marks.
System.out.println(student.getForename() + " " +     student.getSurname());
System.out.println("Module 0: " + student.getModuleMark(0));
System.out.println("Module 1: " + student.getModuleMark(1));
System.out.println("Module 7: " + student.getModuleMark(7));
  } 



private String forename;
private String surname;
private double[] marks;

public Student(String forename, String surname) {
  super();
  this.forename = forename;
  this.surname = surname; 

  marks = new double [8]; //Creates array of fixed size 7
}

/**
 * @return the forename
 */
 public String getForename() { 
    return this.forename;
 }

 /**
  * @return the surname
  */
 public String getSurname() {
   return this.surname;
 }

 /**
  * @param marks the marks to set
  * @param i 
  */     
 public double getModuleMark (int in) {
   return this.marks[in];        
 }

 public void setModuleMark(int in, double marks) {

this.marks[in] = marks;
```

}
}

Comment: check this one............ First of all you had created the array of 7 elements but you were trying to set and get the 8th element value which will show index out of bound error.        Check this one I modified your code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, you must firstly add

`private double [] ModuleMark`

as a Student Class field, and then something like

```
public double getModuleMark (int in){
   return this.ModuleMark[in];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your student can have many modules each having its mark then basically an array is suitable for your use case. So you need to remove `double marks` and keep only the array `double [] ModuleMark`.

You could implement your getter and setter like this:

```
public double getModuleMark (int in) {
    return ModuleMark[in];
}

public void setModuleMark(int in, double mark) {
    ModuleMark[in] = mark;
}
```

Just beware of [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) . Better yet I would suggest use an [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) witch can grow automatically, it has also the ability to access elements using (zero-based) index.

Also please consider java naming conventions for members and classes.

Answer (score 0):

First ModuleMark should be moduleMark by convention.  :-)

Second your using getters and Setters should be like this (by convention) for moduleMarks.

```
 public double[] getModuleMark() {
return moduleMark;
 }
 public void setModuleMark(double[] moduleMark) {
this.moduleMark = moduleMark;
 }
```

Third -- the scope of module marks might be like this: (defined not just in scope of the student constructor)

```
   public class Student {
      private double [] moduleMark = new double [7]; 
    ....
```

Then, if I think your trying to do this:

```
    // Add some marks to the student.
    student.setSpecificModuleMark(0, 10);
    student.setSpecificModuleMark(1, 80);
    student.setSpecificModuleMark(6, 50);

    // Display the marks.
    System.out.println(student.getForename() + " " + student.getSurname());
    System.out.println("Module 0: " + student.getSpecificModuleMark(0));
    System.out.println("Module 1: " + student.getSpecificModuleMark(1));
    System.out.println("Module 6: " + student.getSpecificModuleMark(6));
   }

private double getSpecificModuleMark(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.moduleMark[i];
   }

private void setSpecificModuleMark(int i, int j) {
    this.moduleMark[i] = j;

   }
```

Fourth: note your trying to print out 7 which is index out of bounds.. so use 0--6.